# How to parameter value in javascript inside formData

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, form-data

I have a form data like this

```
var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
```

(inside a on submit fonction)

I would like to get the value of a parameter inside this formData.
For example in a sign up form,

```
formData.name
```

It's undefined.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FormData is a 'one way' object to prepare a request. You can only append data. If you want to get data from a specific field in the form, you will need to use val() like this:

```
$('input[name="your-field-name"]', this).val(); // where this is the context (your form)
```

Comment: Thanks, I already thought about this, just wanted to know if it was possible with formData. I'll continue this way.

Answer (score 0):

The correct method to get FormData from a form element would be

```
var formData = this.getFormData();
```